# configured a downloaded package with ./configure, how to remove it completely from centos

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile

did following in setup.sh and creating a docker image

```
wget -qO- 
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.8/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz | tar zvx
rm zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.8
./configure
make
make install
```

at the end of docker file want to remove all binaries of this package to reduce the size of docker, How to do that

Comment: where is your `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to run `make uninstall` after you have done what you want with this library + remove `zlib-1.2.8` folder. Your `Dockerfile` should look like :

```
FROM    centos:7

RUN     ./setup.sh \
 &&     ./do_stuff_with_zlib.sh \
 &&     ./uninstall_zlib.sh
```

The `uninstall_zlib.sh` script should contain :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

(cd zlib-1.2.8; make uninstall) # uninstall binaries
rm zlib-1.2.8                   # also remove folder to gain some space
```

Note that `./setup.sh` and `./uninstall_zlib.sh` should be run in the same layer (same `RUN` directive), otherwise resulting image size will not be reduced (unless you squash it afterwards).

Comment: also I'm installing RUN yum install -y devtoolset-6 which is 331 MB when I do RUN yum remove -y devtoolset-6 . It does not remove 331MB

Comment: That's why you should install and remove in the same layer (same `RUN`). Otherwise dependency will still be present in an intermediate layer. You can also run `--squash` option when running `docker build` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/#options) if experimental features are enabled on your Docker daemon. Note also that removing a package does not always remove all that have been installed (for example, dependencies may have been updated, ...). So you'll probably never get -331MB when removing.